# Compiler Error "cannot be applied"?

Tags: java, arrays, object, compiler-errors

Having an issue getting this method to work. It's in a separate class calling onto another object class to conduct a search through an array of books. I have 3 other similar methods that are conducting a search as well but for different queries.

```
public static void searchForTitle(Book[] theBooks)
   {
      String message;
      String searchTitle;
      searchTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter title to search");
      message = Book.findBookByTitle(theBooks, searchTitle);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
   }//end searchForTitle method
```

This is the method in the object class that corresponds with the above mentioned method, I can't seem to find the problem here and the compiler error I receive for all 4 methods that are conducting the searches come up as:

```
TestBook.java:73: findBookByTitle(java.lang.String,Book[]) in Book cannot be applied to (Book[],java.lang.String)
      message = Book.findBookByTitle(theBooks, searchTitle);
```

OBJECT METHOD BELOW

```
public static String findBookByTitle(String titleSearched, Book[] arrayOfBooks)
{
  String message = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < getNumberOfBooks(); i++)
  {
     if(titleSearched.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayOfBooks[i].getTitle()))
     {
        message = message + arrayOfBooks[i].toString();
     }//end if
  }//end for  
  return message;
}//end findByTitle
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? Have you read it carefully?

Comment: Remember that in scala, functions are "applied" to the parameters. So here, the "cannot be applied" statement is telling you that the function and the parameters are not compatible. In the error messages, it shows you that the order (Book[] then String vs String then Book[]) is incorrect.

Comment: @quazzieclodo got one portion of it after sifting through it again I found the rest of the error, simple mix up of order. I always find it AFTER I post jeez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters are in the wrong order. Change it to:

```
message = Book.findBookByTitle(searchTitle, theBooks);
```